# How to import a c++ module from another library?

Tags: c++, c++20

I've got a c++ project called `core` that compiles successfully and produces a dll and a lib file when compiled on Windows. Now I need to import functionality from `core` in another project called `main`. `core` has a file called `core.module.ifc`:

```
export module core
export import :mod
export import :egx
export import :utils
```

In my `main` project, I have a single `demo.cpp` which looks like this:

```
#include "someOtherLib.h"

import std.core // error occurs here
import core
.....
some other code
```

However, `main` does not compile with error:

```
1>C:\Users\main\Desktop\Projects\demo\src\demo.cpp(8,11): error C2230: could not find module 'core'
```

I am using VS 16 2019 to compile, with `std::c++latest` and platform toolset v142. The core.lib file is correctly given as input to the linker in the project's properties. From what I understand, the compiler has no way of knowing that core is an outside library and looks for `export module core` in the demo project (which obviously fails) and requires a file that has all the declarations of the `core` lib. Am I correct on this assumption? If so, how would this file look?

So I believe a summary of my question would be, how do I import a module that is exported from a library into my project?

Comment: You may want to read Microsoft's documentation on [VS2019 Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I forgot to enable the compiler modules extension, thanks. Edited my question.