# Importing a C++ module from an external shared library (error C2230)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I've got 2 C++ project in the same Visual Studio solution: `Engine`, a library; and `Test`, that uses the `Engine` library

`Engine` compiles correctly on Windows and produces a lib and a dll. The lib is correctly given to the linker of `Test` as well

In `Test`, I try to import a module from `Engine`, but the compiler fails with error C2230

Here are code excerpts from the 2 projects:

`Engine` > *hal.ixx*

```cpp
export module hal;

#ifdef TEST_ENGINE_EXPORTS
#define TEST_ENGINE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TEST_ENGINE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

import <string>;

export extern TEST_ENGINE_API void prepareMain();
export extern TEST_ENGINE_API int init();
//...
```

`Test` > *main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdio.h>

import hal;            //fails here: error C2230 could not find module 'hal'

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{

    prepareMain();
    // some other stuff...
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (v. 17.4.0), and for the 2 projects, I compile with std::c++latest, /permissive- and /experimental:module. I've also added the `Engine` header's folder as Additional include directory for the `Test` project.
I've tried to remove the module altogether and including headers files in `Test` and functions are correctly called

I already read this question ([How to import a c++ module from another library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018125/how-to-import-a-c-module-from-another-library)) that has the same problem that me, and the article linked in one comment ([VS2019 Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)), but I fail to see how it can solve my problem

**EDIT**

So, I ran a couple of tests, and basically, it seems to stem from the fact that my library is a dll project

I tried making a new solution with 2 projects

The library one is a WindowsStaticLib project. Compiler options are : `/std:c++latest`, `/std:c17`, `/permissive-`, `/experimental:module`, and `/sdl` and `/W3` (last 2 where there by default, I let them as they were). I deactivated precompiled headers since it seemed to interfere with modules (compliling amodule unit with `/exportHeader` as it is recommended [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c7612-when-importing-standard-library-headers/1523264) when module import standard header was causing VS to start looking for pch.h in  header)

For the actual project using the library; library project is added as a reference, compiler options are the same as the library project, lib headers directory is added to VC++ directories > External include directories, lib folder to Library directories, and .lib file added as an Additional dependancy

Everything works.
Module is correctly found and imported, and functions can be called from the actual project.
As a side note, I should add that I didn't need to specify my module functions as `extern` for them to be usable in the other project `main.cpp`. I thought I should have done it but apparently not.

Now I tried to do the same thing but with a DLL project for the library. New solution with 2 project, with the exact same configuration as it was for the previous solution.
Error C2230 when I try to import my module in the actual project `main.cpp`.

Does anyone know something about this ?
Is it normal behaviour that I just didn't know ?

Comment: I suppose so, but, just to be sure, are you passing `-I<folder_where_hall_ixx_lives>` as a compile option?

Comment: @rturrado Is it the Additional include directories option in Project properties > C/C++ > General ? If that's the case, then yes, I added the header's folder of the lib

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right, I didn't pay attention to that. I removed the line.

I've edited my question

Comment: I cannot think of much more tests. Just make sure the module name doesn't include dots or hyphens (e.g. `export module hal.ixx`; or `import hal.ixx;`). And I may try 1) moving the `import hal;` line before the `#include` lines, and 2), turn those `#include` lines at `main.cpp` into `import` lines as well.

Comment: @rturrado I've tried both and none of them worked.
I'm not sure about the name, it is `hal`, imported as `hal`, in *hal.ixx*. But I do have another module named `hal.output` in an *output.ixx* file, that is exported-imported in *hal.ixx*. I've done this after [this article](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/03/10/modules-1.html). Is it wrong ?
I know I could have used partitions, but I wanted to try this method since it seemed to allow me to control whether I wanted to include some functions or not (while it would have been mandatory to import a partition)

Comment: @rturrado
Just to be sure, I tried to replace `hal.output` by a partition `hal:output` (and export-import with `export import :output;` in *hal.ixx*), but that didn't work either

Comment: @MetaZenithian: There is some [slight evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38078341/734069) that you shouldn't use macros for these things in modules. `dllexport` on an exported entity automatically becomes `dllimport` when you import that module. Or at the very least, the consuming code should not define the macro differently.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for the informations (that didn't change anything nonetheless). I actually tried several different things that shed more light on where does the issue comes from (but raised more questions than before for me)
I edited my initial post to add the results of my tests

Comment: Is it even possible to export a c++20 module from a DLL?
I succeed in building the DLL-project. But the project (in the same VS solution) that tries to consume the module fails to build with compile error C2230.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. A solution would be great.

Comment: @RanRegev it is possible see also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75458943/1848032

Answer (score 0):

MSVC Dlls with C++20 Modules are usable. **Ensure two things:**

1. Items to be exported are either dll-exported e.g.,
   `export __declspec(dllexport) int FunctionInDllExample(int x);`
   or
   exported from an exports file (.def file).
2. In project properties: "VC++ Directories -> "All Modules are Public" is set to Yes.

I have tested that dll export from a C++20 module in a dll works properly.

Reference for module definition (exports) file:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=msvc-170
(The term "module" in "module definition file" does not refer to C++20 modules because .def files have been in use for decades. So don't be confused by that. [However the term "module" may be a precursor to C++20 modules.])